# Django/Python: Return JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

I can't seem to find the proper way to return a JSON list in Django. Every method I choose gives me an error.

Here is what I have

```
def filter(request):
    results = Profile.objects.all
    results_json = serializers.serialize('json', results )
    return HttpResponse( results_json, mimetype='application/json' )
```

I get this error `'instancemethod' object is not iterable`

So I changed it to...

```
def filter(request):
    results = Profile.objects.all
    results_json = serializers.serialize('json', [results] )
    return HttpResponse( results_json, mimetype='application/json' )
```

Now I get this error: `'function' object has no attribute '_meta'`

How can I properly return a JSON object?

Answer (score 2):

```
results = Profile.objects.all
```

needs to be

```
results = Profile.objects.all()
```

so that you actually call the `QuerySet`'s `all` method, rather than just reference it. The serializer should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your problems (the one before and the one after the change) are un-related to Django or JSON. The error is because of your choice of `filter` as the name of the function. `filter` is a name of Python's built-in [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) which causes the python interpreter to interpret your method differently when invoked in the context of the django view object.

Comment: nope. I changed the method and it still is giving me the same error

Comment: @user2158382 He still has a valid point naming functions and variables the same as the built-in functions will cause you extremely confusing bugs in the future.